# Symfony 3 - Native query to fetch options for EntityType in form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4

I have a form in which I have one of the fields connected to entity:

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
                'class' => ProductCategory::class,
                'required' => true,
                'query_builder' => function(ProductCategoryRepository $repo) {
                    return $repo->createCategoryStructuredQuery();
                }
            ))
```

However in the repo I have to use following query:

```
SELECT c.* FROM product_category c order by coalesce(c.parentid, c.id), c.parentid is not null, c.name
```

Doctrine throws exceptions because of coalesce and is not null in order clause, I have created a native query inside createCategoryStructuredQuery():

```
public function createCategoryStructuredQuery() {
    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();

    $rsm->addEntityResult('ProductBundle\Entity\ProductCategory', 'c');

    $nativeQuery = $this->getEntityManager()
            ->createNativeQuery(
                'SELECT c.* 
                FROM product_category c 
                order by coalesce(c.parentid, c.id), 
                      c.parentid is not null, 
                      c.name',
                      $rsm
            );
}
```

How can I return a QueryBuilder instance to assign it properly to the form field? Or how can I properly build a doctrine query as above using query builder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `COALESCE` directly in query builder. In fact you can just add it to `SELECT` statement and then use it for ordering. What you need is to declare this field as `HIDDEN` in order to excluding it from final result.

```
->add('category', EntityType::class, array(
    'class' => ProductCategory::class,
    'required' => true,
    'query_builder' => function(ProductCategoryRepository $repo) {
        return $repo->createQueryBuilder('pc')
            ->select('pc, COALESCE(pc.parentid, pc.id) as HIDDEN orderId, -pc.parentId AS HIDDEN inverseParentId')
            ->orderBy('orderId', 'ASC')
            ->addOrderBy('inverseParentId', 'DESC')
            ->addOrderBy('pc.name', 'ASC')
            ->getQuery()->getResult();
    }
));
```

Comment: Thank you DrKey. I use the solution with selecting COALESCE but it was breaking my entity creation due to additional element in select - but HIDDEN made the work.

However I still missing the part in orderby: c.parentid is not null

Answer (score 0):

As I can see the code, Doctrine's exception is just the beginning. Your function doesn't return any value although it should. Secondly, you have to execute getResult() method on $nativeQuery variable you created. Thirdly, even if you returned the result of getResult() method it'd still not be a queryBuilder object (as callback in form expects) but an array.

Why don't you just stay inside the callback function and return:

```
return $repo->createQueryBuilder('c')
    // here build your query with qb functions, e.g. ->orderBy(arg1 [, arg2])
```

Comment: I have forgotten to put that in the code snippet, but it of course returns queryBuilder object